# Catch the Click Event of the Hyperlink from the Entire String in Android

Tags: android

I am receiving a String Response from the WebService which I have stored in a String Variable.

Sometimes I get the Hyperlinks in that String Response for Which I have implemented the Logic to Catch the Link.

I m showing that String Response in an Alert Dialog.

My Concern is that I need to Open the Link on the Click to that Link, not as soon as it find the Link in the String which is the Case happening right now.

My Code :

```
String strTipsMessage = beanTXTIconShowTips.getTips();
                if (strTipsMessage.contains("http")) 
                {
                    String strHyperLink = strTipsMessage.substring(strTipsMessage.indexOf("http"), strTipsMessage.length());
                    if (strHyperLink != null)  
                    {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        intent.setData(Uri.parse(strHyperLink));
                        startActivity(intent); 
                    }

                    AndroidLog.i(TAG, "strHyperLink : --- " + strHyperLink); 
                    AndroidLog.i(TAG, "Tips_Message : --- > " + strTipsMessage);
                }
```

Utility.showDialogForTips(ActConversations.this, "Tip of the Day...", strTipsMessage, R.drawable.icon_tips, "Ok");

Thanks,
David

Comment: have you set the value of text in a textview???

Comment: can you explain you problem a little more,  now its not clear what you want to do

Comment: As in your code right now is, you are getting the value and if its a url you are starting a WebView intent. That is why a webview is opening when there is some url...

Comment: @BBdev_ right, but I want to Open the Link when I Click that Hyperlink not without my Click

Comment: I have given the solution for that it will only open the link if you click on the textview.

Answer (score 0):

I think `Linkify` is the thing which you are looking for. You can make your text linked to some URL so when it gets clicked, it function appropriately.

Refer [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/util/Linkify.html) and [this](http://www.indelible.org/ink/android-linkify/) link.

Answer (score 0):

As i under stood your problem. I can suggest you to make a `TextView` and `set the text or the url value` to that TextView. Add a click listener to that TextView and fire the intent when a user clicks the url text.

**Code**

```
TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.url);
t.setText("http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html");
t.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
```

here is the listener which listen the textview click

```
OnClickListener clickListener = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        TextView vi = (TextView) v;
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), vi.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse(vi.getText()));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```